# SQL Server / Oracle Linked -- Julian Date Error

Tags: sql-server, oracle, view, linked-server, julian-date

I have a client who has a SQL Server 2000 database linked to an Oracle 8i database. They have dozens of views in the SQL Server 2000 database which reference the Oracle database, often with simple syntax such as:

```
SELECT *
FROM  SERVER..DB.TABLE
```

These views (and the sprocs which reference them) have worked for YEARS without issue. Suddenly, this morning, some (but not all) of them are failing with the following error:

```
Server: Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SALES_ORDER_HEADERS, Line 7
Could not fetch a row from OLE DB provider 'MSDAORA'. 
[OLE/DB provider returned message: ORA-01854: julian date must be between 1 and 5373484]
OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'MSDAORA' IRowset::GetNextRows returned 0x80040e07].
```

When we select data using the four-part syntax above (the same syntax as the view has defined), the queries succeed without issue and the . However, we cannot create a view on that syntax, we cannot edit the existing views (in the designer), and we cannot figure out why directly querying the linked table works, but using it via a query fails.

My company didn't build the system, nor do we generally maintain it -- the client has an internal dev team which works on it, but they asked for our troubleshooting help, and we're just as stumped as they are, so I figured I'd ask here.

Anyone have any clue why we'd see this behavior -- and more importantly, how to correct it? (Short of upgrading; not an option at this point.) As a temporary workaround, we've discovered that using `OPENQUERY` does function, but it is of course dog slow. We'd like a solution which doesn't involve `OPENQUERY`, if possible.

In response to the comments: There is no `ORDER BY` defined in the views. There may be in the sprocs, but I'm not certain. (I just saw this database for the first time about 20 minutes before posting the question. :) )

Comment: Is there "ORDER BY" in your views or sprocs? This could be the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a change on data have happened that not happened on years. I found something similar years ago, I was developing a critical application module, testing, testing, testing for a lot of use-cases and all fine, and the day on production a non-tested pattern was introduced! Incredible but true!

Because that change on data something wrong is giving to some kind of `TO_CHAR(xx, 'J')` call. For example, zero or negative data.

Because a lot of calls are falling may be is a base table/column common to all.

Actions:

- Activate [trace](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Trace_events) for the session in Oracle (you can do it for an [active session](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/8i/DBMS_System.php) and for an error number).
- Look for "common denominator" tables/columns and then for strange values.

Comment: Heard back from the client this morning; that's exactly what he found on the Oracle side. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is there "ORDER BY" in your views, this could be the cause.